# Cannot register two routes matching for method GET

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I'm building a API with PHP with Slim Framework and I hove a problem with my router. When I try to use different routes with the same HTTP verb I get **FastRoute\BadRouteException**. Is there a way to use the same HTTP verb for different routs?

**routes.php**

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$routes = file(_APP . '/config/routes.cfg');

foreach ($routes as $index => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '#') !== FALSE) {
        continue;
    } else if (count(explode(' ', $line)) < 3) {
        continue;
    }
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line);
    $route = explode(' ', $line);

    $mapping1 = $app->{$route[0]}($route[1] . '/', explode('::', $route[2]));
    $mapping2 = $app->{$route[0]}($route[1], explode('::', $route[2]));

    if (isset($route[3]) && strlen($route[3]) > 0) {
        if (strpos($route[3], '|') !== FALSE) {
            $middlewares = explode('|', $route[3]);
            foreach ($middlewares as $middleware) {
                if (strlen($middleware) > 0) {
                    $mapping1->add(explode('::', $middleware));
                    $mapping2->add(explode('::', $middleware));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $mapping1->add(explode('::', $route[3]));
            $mapping2->add(explode('::', $route[3]));
        }
    }
}
```

**routes.cfg**

```
# User Routes
GET /user UserController::select Middleware::connection
POST /user UserController::insert Middleware::connection
PUT /user UserController::update Middleware::connection
PUT /user UserController::changePassword Middleware::connection
DELETE /user UserController::delete Middleware::connection
```

**Complete Stack:**

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: FastRoute\BadRouteException
Message: Cannot register two routes matching "/usuario/" for method "PUT"
File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/DataGenerator/RegexBasedAbstract.php
Line: 55
Trace

#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/DataGenerator/RegexBasedAbstract.php(18): FastRoute\DataGenerator\RegexBasedAbstract->addStaticRoute('PUT', Array, 'route6')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/RouteCollector.php(36): FastRoute\DataGenerator\RegexBasedAbstract->addRoute('PUT', Array, 'route6')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Router.php(227): FastRoute\RouteCollector->addRoute(Array, '/usuario/', 'route6')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/functions.php(24): Slim\Router->Slim\{closure}(Object(FastRoute\RouteCollector))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Router.php(238): FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Router.php(191): Slim\Router->createDispatcher()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(546): Slim\Router->dispatch(Object(Slim\Http\Request))
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(470): Slim\App->dispatchRouterAndPrepareRoute(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Router))
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(122): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(370): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(295): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/soccerama_api/index.php(55): Slim\App->run()
#12 {main}
```

Comment: `PUT /user UserController::update Middleware::connection
PUT /user UserController::changePassword Middleware::connection`

Same route same verb?

Comment: The method on the controller is different.

Comment: You cannot map `PUT /user` two times, the process won't be able to differentiate when to call which controller@action. The routes signature should be unique; a signature is `[http verb] route`.

Comment: @RaghavGarg so how would I be able to create a new route pointing to another controller? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: either change http verb like, `PATCH /user` or change the route name `PUT /user/reset-password` (suggested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the same HTTP verb for different routs?

You are asking about same HTTP verb and different route, yet in your code you have, same HTTP verb and same route `PUT /user`.

Routes signature should be unique, so that process can map uniquely a `route` to the `conroller@action`. A route signature is `[http verb] [route]`

Please try a different route or different HTTP verb.

```
// different route (suggested in your case)
PUT /user/reset-password

// different HTTP verb
PATCH /user
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the framework would take the controller and include in the route but I now realize that this wouldn't happen. Thank you so much for the help.